# dataTables custom filtering of <tr> if cell contains value

Tags: jquery, filter, datatables

How can I filter datatable rows which contain a cell with a specific value?  I need to show either all rows, or only the rows with a specific value "A" in a specific column.

```
        <tr>
            <td>...</td>
            <td>...</td>
            <td>...</td>
            <td>...</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
```

Here is an example of filtering by row class, but the data source I will have will not provide row classes.

The example uses:

```
    $.fn.dataTableExt.afnFiltering.push(function (oSettings, aData, iDataIndex) {    
      var myRowClasses = oSettings.aoData[iDataIndex].nTr.className.split(" ");
      var grade = $('.grade-check:checked').data('grade');    
      return myRowClasses.indexOf(grade) > -1;
    });
```

I need to change this so that it looks for rows with which have the td value instead of rows with a class name.

http://jsfiddle.net/lbriquet/d2b6vmdm/3/

Thank you in advance for your help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some issues here. First of all, you could reduce the redundant handling of the `RadioGroup1` elements :

```
$('[name="RadioGroup1"]').change(function () {
   oTable.fnDraw();
});
```

The radio buttons dont need an `id` at all :

```
<label>
   <input type="radio" name="RadioGroup1" class="grade-check" data-grade="*" />
   All grades
</label>
```

have added `C` and `X` to the forked fiddle below, and changed "gradeAll" to a simple `*`. Now you can create the filter :

```
$.fn.dataTableExt.afnFiltering.push(function (oSettings, aData, iDataIndex) {
    var filter = $('input[name=RadioGroup1]:checked').data('grade'),
        grade = aData[4];
    return grade == filter || filter == "*";
});
```

forked fiddle -> **http://jsfiddle.net/vs0cagLj/**

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!  I am just running into a problem with another function.  It seems to be tied to the asterisk filter for show all